# How do I interpret iOS EXC_BREAKPOINT crash report?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash-reports

I have an iOS App that crashes with certain users. I can't recreate the crash however I do have three identical crash reports. How can I figure out what is causing the crash? (I've looked at https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/414/ but am still having difficulties.)

Exerpt from the crash report is as follows:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100fd21ac
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [5535]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100fd21ac 0x100de0000 + 2040236
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100fd21ac 0x100de0000 + 2040236
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000101027c50 0x100de0000 + 2391120
3   MyApp                           0x000000010081af08 partial apply for closure #3 in DefaultService.processPosts(network:posts:completion:) + 40 (DefaultService.swift:1009)
4   MyApp                           0x000000010087060c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 36 (<compiler-generated>:0)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000021aeb96c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1372)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000021aeba484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:511)
```

The code that seems to be causing the problem `DefaultService.swift:1009` in `processPosts` is as follows:

```
private func processPosts(network: Network, posts: [Post], completion: @escaping (Result<Void>) -> Void) {
   ...
   dg.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.savePosts(network: network, posts: posts) // This is line 1009.
        completion(.success(()))
    }
}

private func savePosts(network: Network, posts: [Post]) {
    let context = self.container().viewContext

    for post in posts {
        // Don't save if already saved.
        if isPostSaved(context: context, network: network,
                            networkPostID: post.networkPostID!) {
            continue
        }

        let np = NetworkPost(context: context)
        np.id = post.id
        np.network = network.rawValue
        np.networkPostID = post.networkPostID
        np.subtitle = post.subtitle
        np.text = post.text

        for image in post.images {
            let npImage = NetworkPostImage(context: context)
            npImage.data = image
            np.addToImages(npImage)
        }
        if let active = post.active {
            np.active = active
        }
        np.created = post.created
    }

    try! context.save()
}

private func isPostSaved(context: NSManagedObjectContext, network: Network, networkPostID: String) -> Bool {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NetworkPost>(entityName: "NetworkPost")
    let format = "(network == %@) AND (networkPostID == %@)"
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: format,
                                         network.rawValue,
                                         networkPostID)

    let posts = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    return !posts.isEmpty
}
```

Is it likely that one of my `try!` calls in either `savePosts` or `isPostSaved` is the culprit causing an `EXC_BREAKPOINT`?

If so how can I narrow down which one it is? Is there any way of using the first three `libswiftCore.dylib` calls of the backtrace to figure it out?

If not the `try!` calls then what else could be causing the `EXEC_BREAKPOINT` error?

Note that I am using the CoreData API in memory only mode so I expect my `try! context.save()` and `try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)` calls to execute unless there is something seriously wrong or I have a programming error. This is why I use `try!` instead of `do { } catch { }`.

Comment: Before interpreting crash reports I recommend to use `do-catch` blocks and *interpret* the **error**.

Comment: I could and probably will end up doing that if this question comes to nothing. However, I can't recreate the error and have no access to the affected users. There's also no guarantee the affected users will use my app again with it continually crashing so I was hoping to give myself the best opportunity to fix the issue first time.

Comment: After further investigation the EXC_BREAKPOINT was coming from `try! context.save()` having a validation error. I would still like to know how I could have inferred that from the crash report.